# How to make regex macros work?

Tags: regex, rust

I followed [this tutorial](http://doc.rust-lang.org/regex/regex/index.html). However, trying to compile the example:

```
#![feature(plugin)]
#[plugin] #[no_link]
extern crate regex_macros;
extern crate regex;

fn main() {
    let re = regex!(r"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$");
    assert_eq!(re.is_match("2014-01-01"), true);
}
```

fails with the following errors:

```
src/main.rs:3:1: 3:27 error: can't find crate for `regex_macros`
src/main.rs:3 extern crate regex_macros;
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
Could not compile `upm`.
```

I added

```
[dependencies]
regex = "0.1.8"
```

to my `Cargo.toml`.

Seems like the doc is deprecated.

I updated rust before:

```
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.0.0-nightly (74b874071 2015-02-08 00:24:03 +0000)
```

Which steps do I have to follow now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The macros are distributed as [their own crate](https://crates.io/crates/regex_macros). You need to add them as a dependency, next to the `regex` crate on your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
regex = "0.1.8"
regex_macros = "0.1.8"
```

Perhaps you could provide a pull request to the appropriate project beefing up the documentation!

Comment: "Perhaps you could provide a pull request to the appropriate project beefing up the documentation! " Show me, how!

Comment: Also, do I have to specify the *exact* version of the package, can't I (or should I) just say "0.1"?

Comment: Teaching someone how to use git and contribute to a project is a big topic that won't fit in a comment ^_^. I'm sure there are good blog posts or similar out there on the Internet. I can get you started by pointing you to the [regex project repository](https://github.com/rust-lang/regex) though.

Comment: I know how to use github and git , so thats no problem :D, however, does posting an issue to the linked repo change the doc I linked to in my question?

Comment: As for specifying a version, that's up to you. You might want to read the [crates.io guide on version specifiers](http://doc.crates.io/crates-io.html) which indicates that `foo = "0.1.0"` is the same as `foo = "^0.1.0"`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. And there already is an issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/regex/issues/31